# Grant Access to App if Liked our page on Facebook?

Tags: mysql, facebook, jquery-mobile

Having googled various iterations and looked at the Facebook info I'm none the wiser.

What I'm looking to do is have the ability to cross reference my business page on Facebook and where a user has Liked our page they can then login to our app, thus if they unlike us their account is disabled?

Basically having written a free app that could be widely used for what our business provides we get a simplified marketing strategy.

The app I have is built around jQuery Mobile and links to a MySQL database.

Would the user register an account with me and then Like us on Facebook for us to cross reference the FaceBook API's? or would I have to have full FaceBook login? Or even worse is this not possible?